# Does the source of a visitor affect the revenue for Google AdSense ads?

Tags: seo, google-adsense, revenue

I'm wondering if two ad clicks are equally valued, if one of them found the site from Google, and the other came from a referral link, would that affect the revenue paid?

How about with a direct visit?

Comment: The volume of traffic you would require to do this test _ceterus paribus_ to determine this would be so high that you would stop bothering with this detail and keep counting the money in your bank instead!!

Comment: @Prasad Hehe, seems legit. That's why I'm asking instead of testing :)

Comment: Its separately calculated for each ad impression AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

Ad clicks are definitely not equal in value. There are so many variables that can effect the cost-per-click (CPC).

Google answers why AdWords users get charged lower then their maximum CPC bids [here](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6297?hl=en).

The other main thing to consider is that Google uses a wide range of advertisers, so different ads will pay/cost different amounts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! May I ask this: is my adsense revenue is equal to (or a fraction of) the money that the relevant AdWords advertiser paid to Google ?

Comment: Log into your adsense account and go to this link - https://www.google.com/adsense/app#accountInformation (Account info page). Beside "Active products" you should see your revenue share percentages per Ad type - Search / Content / Video...